# DomPDF render different on the Server

Tags: php, html, css, dompdf

I just started using domPDF for my letterhead. On localhost everything works just fine. I put it then on my Server and it looks totally different.

[Render via Localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pvRm.png)
[Render on Server (marked)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnMWO.png)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1210)

Comment: You lost your all CSS somehow